# Passing variable from JQUERY to PHP doesn't work properly (unindentified index)

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a game panel written in php, jquery and using BASH scripts on the server (ubuntu). I can create, stop, start, restart and delete many types of game servers. So far so good.

In the past two days I've been struggling with another issue, displaying the console for each hosted game server. On the Ubuntu server I've created a BASH script which starts and stops screens by retrieving an ID every time a user clicks a button. On the `screen` I use the `-L` command in order to create  a screenlog file. From that log file I am retrieving data using `tail` and then I am updating the file every few seconds using the code bellow:

```
 function Ajax()
    {
        var
            $http,
            $self = arguments.callee;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            $http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                $http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            } catch(e) {
                $http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
        }

        if ($http) {
            $http.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
                    document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
                    setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 1000);
                }
            };
            $http.open('GET', 'loadtxt.php' + '?' + new Date().getTime(), true);
            $http.send(null);
        }

    }
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
include "SSH/Net/SSH2.php";
include "SSH/Net/ANSI.php";
include "dbconn.php";

echo $service = intval($_POST['pid']);

$ssh = new Net_SSH2("137.xxx.xxx.xxx");
@$ansi = new File_ANSI();
if (!$ssh->login('xxxxx', 'xxxxx')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
    }else{
      echo "Connected To Server!";
        $ssh->setTimeout(1);
        @$ansi->appendString($ssh->read());
        } 

    $filename = "/home/$service/screenlog.0";  
    $output = $ssh->exec('exec tail -n10 ' . $filename);
    echo str_replace(PHP_EOL, ' ', $output);   
    $ssh->disconnect()  
?>
```

My problem starts here: I want to use a modal window to display the console (explained above) every time a user clicks a button called "Console". Here is the HTML code I am using for the modal window:

```
 <div class="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p><div id="console">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function() {Ajax();}, 1000);
    </script>
    <div id="ReloadThis">Loading..</div>
  </div></p>
 </div>
```

And the jquery code:

```
      $( function() {
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog({

      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( ".consolebtn" ).on( "click", function() {
        var pid = $(this).data('pid');
        $.post( "loadtxt.php", { pid: pid });
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  } );
```

I am using this piece of code to display every game server created.

```
  <?php
  if($query->rowCount()):
   foreach($rows as $row){ ?>
     <tr>
       <td><?php echo $row['serviceID']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['clientID']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['serviceName']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['serviceType']; ?></td>
       <td><a data-pid = <?php echo $row['serviceID']; ?> class='startbtn' href= 'javascript:void(0)'><button>Start</button></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <a class='stopbtn' data-pid=<?php echo $row['serviceID']; ?> href='javascript:void(0)'><button>Stop</button></a>
       &nbsp;<a data-pid = <?php echo $row['serviceID']; ?> class='restartbtn' href= 'javascript:void(0)'><button>Restart</button></a>&nbsp;
       <a data-pid = <?php echo $row['serviceID']; ?> class="consolebtn" href= 'javascript:void(0)'><button>Console</button></a>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
   <?php }  ?>
  <?php endif;  ?>
```

Every record in the database is displayed on the page with 4 buttons: Start, Stop, Restart and Console. The serviceID is stored in each button so the value is transmitted via the PHP code to the BASH script on the server. However, when the jquery code sends the `pid` with the serviceID, the modal displays an erroor saying that the `pid` variable in `echo $service = intval($_POST['pid']);` is an unidentified index. But the variable is actually sent? I wrote a query to test it out and it worked:

```
try {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM services WHERE serviceID = :service";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':service', $service);
    $query->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error delete';
    exit();

}
```

Now when pressing the Console button the record is deleted and the modal window appears with the same problem of the unidentified index. The only way to make it work is to put the actual ID in the loadtxt.php file but this means it will never work automatically for each game server:

[Modal window with the game console and pid error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAmc3.png)

I really don't know how to solve this. Can anyone give me some advice? I just started working with PHP and Jquery and internet is my best source of knowledge so far.

**EDIT: (as I am not sure I am allowed to make another post about a related issue)**

The console display works great now. But I also want to introduce commands using a submit form inside the modal. The html code, inside the modal display code:

```
  <form id="my_form_id">
    Command: <input type="text" name="screen_input" id="screen_input">
    <input type="submit" />
  <form>
```

This is the javascript code I am using to pass the input from the user into the php file:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#my_form_id').on('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var screen_input = $('#screen_input').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'insert.php',
                    data: {screen_input: screen_input},
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

And here is the PHP that receives the input and sends it to the game console on the server:

```
<?php
//Extra Libs
include "SSH/Net/SSH2.php";
include "SSH/Net/ANSI.php";

$command = $_POST['screen_input'];

   $ssh = new Net_SSH2("137.74.106.13");
    @$ansi = new File_ANSI();
     if (!$ssh->login('test', 'Irefutabil1,.@')) {
     exit('Login Failed');
          }else{
           echo "Connected To Server!";
            $ssh->setTimeout(5);
             $ansi->appendString($ssh->read());
            }
        $command = preg_replace('/\s+/', '\ ', $command);
        echo $ssh->exec("screen -S service253 -p 0 -X stuff " . $command . "'^M'");
        $ssh->disconnect();
?>
```

If I am using the actual serviceID I can easily send input toward the console. However, I need it to take the ID automatically for each console window. How could I send both the serviceID and the input command to the php file so I can run the BASH command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every few seconds you are running this:

`$http.open('GET', 'loadtxt.php' + '?' + new Date().getTime`

Which makes a `GET` request to a file containing this:

`echo $service = intval($_POST['pid']);`

Each time you do that `$_POST['pid']` is undefined and throws an error.

You should wrap it in a conditional:

```
if (!empty($_POST['pid'])) {
    echo $service = intval($_POST['pid']);
}
```

Or change it to `echo $service = intval($_REQUEST['pid']);` so that your variable can be set using a `GET` or a `POST` request, then in your javascript somewhere, outside of any functions declare pid as global variable like this `var pid;`

Now `pid` is available globally, so to all your code. In your onclick function this gets set to the value of the service id, so you can change this line to include it:

```
$http.open('GET', 'loadtxt.php' + '?' + new Date().getTime(), true);
```

like this:

```
$http.open('GET', 'loadtxt.php' + '?pid='+pid+'&s=' + new Date().getTime(), true);
```

Now your service ID gets passed with your setup and your update requests to the server.

Comment: Thanks you for your response. I tried it and it didn't work. If I wrap the $service = intval($_POST['pid']) it can't be used by other queries.  It gets isolated from the rest of the code. If I wrap the whole code it doesn't work at all.

Comment: It gets isolated from the other code if `$_POST['pid']` isn't set, because thats whats throwing your error. Every time this line of your ajax function runs `$http.open('GET', 'loadtxt.php' + '?' + new Date().getTime(), true);` then `$_POST['pid']` isn't set.

Comment: Is there a way I can solve this issue without drastically changing my code? I have little experience in Jquery and Ajax. Close to none actually.

Comment: Is the console window only available once the user has clicked the button which makes the `POST` request?

Comment: Yes. When the button is clicked the modal window pops up and it displays the log file. Each service has its own ID so the script knows which service console to display.

Comment: It doesn't, thats your entire problem. It knows which console to display when the button is clicked but then your code to refresh the console every 10 seconds contains no reference to the service ID. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I changed the lines and added the var pid; on the top of my external .js file. However, whatever console button I am clicking will result in pid value being 0.

Comment: Sorry, in your onclick function change this `var pid = $(this).data('pid');` to `pid = $(this).data('pid');`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. However I just hit another issue. I added the issue in the main post (EDIT).

Comment: Either add a hidden field in your console form and set it to the service ID via javascript, or set a cookie containing the service id and read it from that

Comment: Could you give me an example. I really don't know how to work with Javascript and I want to finish this function as soon as possible. Anyhow, thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually as your `pid` variable is global you could just add it here `data: {screen_input: screen_input, pid: pid},` You have deleted some of your code now, but to clear an old session from the console window you could add a line of code to your onclick function for the button which replaces the console window content with the loading message again

Comment: Your idea worked great! All I had to do is add a global variable to take the value of the console pid whenever the Submit button is clicked and then modify the "data". Thank you!